# Android Calculator Delete Button - Cannot Find Symbol Method substring(int,int)

Tags: android, substring

I'm trying to make a basic calculator in android and the delete button is giving me trouble. If the length is greater than 0, I want it to delete the last digit when the button is pressed, here's what I have so far:

```
public void btnDeciOnClick(View v) {
    int displayLength = displayBar.length();
    if( displayLength > 0 ) {
        displayBar = substring(0, displayLength - 1);
    }
}
```

displayBar was originally a TextView but while trying to find a solution to this I noticed everyone uses EditText so I tried switching it to that to see if it resolved the problem (no luck obviously). The error it's giving me is:

```
error: cannot find symbol method substring(int,int)
```

I'm doing this in Android Studio 2.1.2 if that makes any difference. Totally new to Android, my background was mostly C++ and a single semester of Java. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. If it's a bad question, I'd like to at least be enlightened as to why so I can avoid such in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
displayBar.setText(displayBar.getText().toString().substring(0, displayLength - 1));
```

Comment: ...yeah it's time to go caffeinate, I'm embarrassed for not seeing it. That worked beautifully, thank you!